# Protractor scroll iframe inside browser window

Tags: javascript, browser, scroll, protractor

How to scroll an iframe-element **inside** normal browser-window?

Following does **not** work (tries to scroll window, not iframe):

```
myPage.myItem().click();
browser.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,10000);").then(function () { ...});
```

Comment: Did u switch to iframe before scrolling it? Can you post that code if possible?

Comment: Yes, I did. Will edit post now

Comment: Can you try scrolling this way - `var frame = element(by.tagName('iframe')); frame.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,10000);").then(function () { ...});` ? frame variable is the iframe window that you switch to.

Comment: my iframe does not have a executeScript() function, it belongs to browser

Comment: I am asking you to switch to the iframe first, then using iframe element can you try to scroll inside iframe? `executeScript()` should be available on the iframe element too like the way its available on browser window. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I switched to the frame and all it says is "undefined is not a function", pointing at "executeScript"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89827/discussion-between-girish-sortur-and-best-where-gives).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution by myself, maybe it helps somebody:

```
       return browser.executeScript(function () {
            var iframe = document.getElementById("myobject");
            var docjument = iframe.contentDocument.body;
            docjument.scrollRight= 111;
            return iframeDoc.scrollRight;
        }).then(...)
```

Works like a charm.

Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Try scrolling inside the frame once you switch to it. Also use `iframe` element to perform scroll and not global `browser` object. Here's how -

```
browser.switchTo().defaultContent() //switches to first frame in DOM
.then(function(){
    var frame = element(by.tagName('iframe'));
    frame.click().then(function(){
        frame.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,10000);").then(function () { ...});
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it, and it seems ro run - however, nothing happens, e.g. scrolling does not happen...